# Send messages separately on multiple recipients FB.UI Send dialog

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, fb.ui

I am using `Fb.ui` send dialog on my website allowing users to share links into recipients messenger inbox directly  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/send-dialog

Now the problem I am facing is if I select multiple users in the dialog it creates a group of people in messenger. I don't want to create the group if multiple users are selected, I want to send them separately. Is there any way to achieve this??? Not able to find any solution till now.

Thanks in advance

Comment: No, that’s not possible.